# SwiftUI recursion

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a view using a recursion. The function works fine in the preview, but once I try to build the app it crashes returning the error below.

> Function opaque return type was inferred as VStack<TupleView<(Text, ForEach<[Tag], Int, Text>, Text, Text, Text?, Text?, ForEach<[Contact], Int, Text>, TupleView<(Text, ForEach<[Tutorial], Int, TupleView<(Text, some View)>>)>?)>>, which defines the opaque type in terms of itself

I have a type Tutorial, which may contain more Tutorials. The subtutorials can be filtered like this: `tutorial.subTutorials.filter { $0.choice != nil }`. The subtutorials are answers to follow up questions. The final product should look like this:

The outcome on android:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
//
//  TempDetail.swift
//  Smart Migration
//
//  Created by Jan Janovec on 15.03.2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TempDetail: View {
    var tutorial: Tutorial = .mock
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            makeContent(for: tutorial)
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder func makeContent(for tutorial: Tutorial) -> some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(tutorial.name)
        ForEach(tutorial.tags) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
        Text(tutorial.lastUpdated ?? "Last updated")
        Text("Text tutoriálu: \(tutorial.id)")
        if let help = tutorial.help {
            Text("ℹ️\(help.header ?? "")")
        }
        if let warning = tutorial.warning {
            Text("⚠️\(warning.header ?? "")")
        }
        ForEach(tutorial.contacts) { item in
            Text("Contact: \(item.name)")
        }
        if tutorial.followUpQuestion != nil {
            Text("❓\(tutorial.followUpQuestion ?? "")")
            ForEach(tutorial.subTutorials.filter { $0.choice != nil }) { item in
                Text("⚜️\(item.choice ?? "")")
                makeContent(for: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TempDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TempDetail(tutorial: .mock)
    }
}
```

I tried to use the function in the code snippet, but it throws.

Answer (score 0):

A SwiftUI view needs to have a known type at compile time so it cannot be defined in terms of itself. You need to break the recursion by having a top level function which creates the main tutorial view and then, if required, iterates over each of the sub tutorials. Something like this:

```
@ViewBuilder func makeContent(for tutorial: Tutorial) -> some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        makeTutorialView(for: tutorial) 
        
        if tutorial.followUpQuestion != nil {
            Text("❓\(tutorial.followUpQuestion ?? "")")
            ForEach(tutorial.subTutorials.filter { $0.choice != nil }) { item in
                Text("⚜️\(item.choice ?? "")")
                makeTutorialView(for: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder func makeTutorialView(for tutorial: Tutorial) -> some View {
    Text(tutorial.name)
    ForEach(tutorial.tags) { item in
        Text(item.name)
    }
    Text(tutorial.lastUpdated ?? "Last updated")
    Text("Text tutoriálu: \(tutorial.id)")
    if let help = tutorial.help {
        Text("ℹ️\(help.header ?? "")")
    }
    if let warning = tutorial.warning {
        Text("⚠️\(warning.header ?? "")")
    }
    ForEach(tutorial.contacts) { item in
        Text("Contact: \(item.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :) Forgot to mention, that sub-tutorials may also contain more sub-tutorials and so on. It is a tree structure and I do not know the depth. I wanted to try displaying it using a recursive view.

Comment: I think you will have to flatten the subtutorials recursion into a single list somehow.